# Guest entries - send confirmation mail to person who filled out entry

Tags: guest-entries

Inherited a site which uses guest entries for a job application form.

Postmaster plugin is being used to notify someone that a new entry has been posted but now they'd also like to send the person who applied for the job a confirmation mail after submitting the guest entries form... any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Does the person that applied have a custom email field on the guest entry?

Comment: Indeed, that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the person that applied has a text field they entered their email address on in the Guest Entry, then the plugin has an [`onSuccess`](https://github.com/craftcms/guest-entries/tree/v1#guestentriessuccess-and-guestentrieserror-events) event that gets fired when a guest entry is successfully saved.

You could listen to that from another plugin, grab their email address from the custom field, then build an email and programatically send it their way.

Comment: so basically I'll need a plugin?

Comment: Yup, that's the way to go.